# Not in array in sails's waterline ORM

Tags: mongodb, orm, sails.js, waterline

How to execute "not in array" query in Sails' waterline ORM that would be equal to mongooses' $nin?

```
Question.find({id: {"!=": [2] } }).exec(function(err, docs){})
```

this example seems not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following query in Sails-Mongo

```
Model.find({ id: { '!': [2,3,4,...] } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [`$nin`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin), which should have been implemented on the adapter level, simply hasn't been added to [`sails-mongo`](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo) yet. At least, there's no sign of it in the current [source code](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/blob/0.9.6/lib/criteria.js).